# Buscar y filtrar URL en un archivo plano (Bash)

Tags: búsquedas, sed, grep

Necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Un script que busque en un archivo plano urls, y si parte de las url coinciden me las imprima en pantalla o las guarde en otro archivo plano.
Por ej si tengo un archivo plano con el siguiente contenido:

```
www.google.com.ar
www.google.com.mx
www.yahoo.com.ar
www.yahoo.com.mx
```

Me recorra el archivo plano, y me muestre:
Salida 1:

```
www.google.com.ar
www.google.com.mx
```

Salida 2:

```
www.yahoo.com.ar
www.yahoo.com.mx
```

> (Aclaración, las urls van a ir variando, no van a ser siempre las
>   mismas y puede haber nuevas urs).

Comment: Interesante. De todos modos, lo bueno sería ver exactamente qué has probado, pues con esos detalles podremos entender mejor la lógica de lo que buscas. Recuerda que trabajar con dominios y subdominios siempre es harto complicado. ¿Qué pasaría con, por ejemplo, deportes.elpais.com y economia.elpais.com?